Orchard Core Multi-Tenant authentication for all the modules(features)
I am trying to develop a multi tenant .NET core application. For Multi-tenancy I have choosen OrchardCore.
My current folder structure is as follows
I have 3 projects.

Empty Web host project which as the host container for all the modules.
Module1 is an mvc application
Module2 is also an mvc application

I have used orchard core and multi tenant along with routing are working fine.
The issue here is
When I am using authentication I have written my code in WebHost-> program.cs file
I am able to redirect to login provider and get the token back to my webhost project.
But when I am using [Authorize] attribute on the MVC controllers of my module projects. I am facing an error
"Module1(Index) contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found...".

In program.cs file of web host project I have specified
app.UseAuthorization()
but still I am unable to authorize my module level controllers.
Please help
Thanks in advance.

Please include your Program.cs
